# How to implement conditional column formatting in a data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with the following data.

```
id  values      val1    val1    val3
1                1       1       0
2                0       0       0
3                1       0       1
4                0       1       0
5                1       1       1
```

I want to populate the data-frame column "values" based on the columns val1, val2, and val3

Expected Result:
If Val1= 1, Add A,  Val2= 1, add B, Val3= 3, add C

```
id  values      val1    val1    val3
1   A-B          1       1       0
2                0       0       0
3   A-C          1       0       1
4   B            0       1       0
5   A-B-C        1       1       1
```

I tried the code similar to the below - but not sure how to add conditional statements,

df["values"] = df["val1"].astype(str).str.cat(df["val2"], sep= '-')

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below accomplishes this task. It goes through the dataframe row by row (`.apply(..., axis=1)`), and for each row it iterates through the columns. Where a column has a value of 1, it appends the appropriate value. Finally, it joins the values together in the second `.apply` function.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': None,
                   'val1': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'val2': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'val3': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'val4': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'val5': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                   })

val_dict = {'val1': 'A',
            'val2': 'B',
            'val3': 'C'}

df['values'] = df.drop(columns='values').apply(
    lambda x: [val_dict[col_name] if (col_name in val_dict and x[col_name]==1) else ''
               for col_name in x.index],
    axis=1
).apply(lambda x: '-'.join([v for v in x if v != '']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The above code works as expected.  I shared the minimum columns in my questions. But My data frame has more columns and the code is breaking. Sorry for not adding the details earlier. If I add anew column in the above code, getting an error

Comment: The code above assumes that `val_dict` and `df` have the same column names. Is it that you only have *some* columns in `val_dict`, and your actual `df` has more columns? Please explain how your actual data is different, that'll help with a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you again. My dataframe has 30+ columns. The conditional column count 6. For example

startdate, empid, locId, fname, lastname,values, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6 engid,pid.

Comment: No problem. Please see my updated answer where I've amended the code.